# What is wrong with this Postgresql query in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

```
q = """DELETE FROM my_table
       WHERE id in ({}) (select id from ({}))""".format(list_of_ids_to_be_deleted)
```

Not sure how to delete rows from the table when I am given a list of indices to be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second part of your query is not needed: just use the provided list.

```
q = """DELETE FROM my_table
       WHERE id in ({})""".format(list_of_ids_to_be_deleted)
```

You might have to build a comma-separated input, similar to

```
q = """DELETE FROM my_table
       WHERE id in ({})""".format(','.join(map(str, list_of_ids_to_be_deleted)))
```